# Python OGR error when intesecting line by polygon

Tags: python, clip, ogr, file-geodatabase, error

When I try to find the intersection of a line gdb layer with a polygon layer I get the following error: ***Can only insert a LineString/MultiLineString/CircularString/CompoundCurve/MultiCurve in a esriGeometryLine layer')***

It works fine for point or polygon layers.

Here is my code:

for cliplayer in aoi_ds:
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('OpenFileGDB').CreateDataSource(outgdb)

```
  outlayer = driver2.CreateLayer(inlayer.GetName(), inlayer.GetSpatialRef(), inlayer.GetGeomType())
  for x in range(defn.GetFieldCount()):
       outlayer.CreateField(defn.GetFieldDefn(x))
  ogr.Layer.Clip(inLayer, inClipLayer, outLayer)  
  inlayer.SetAttributeFilter('')
  inlayer.ResetReading()
```

How can I filter out the points being created in the clip command?

Comment: Maybe some polygon only touches some linestring, which yields a point as an intersection. Try to filter the intersection geometries by a geometry type for removing points.

Comment: How would I do that before it is written out. Is there a way to do that with ogr.

Comment: I have figured out that this is the problem, not sure how to fix it.